# Pentaho Kettle spoon - How to create a list of 31 columns of floating type data to check it is NULL/NOT NULL

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, spoon

Case:

TestCompany Corporation is sending us expenditure data in a csv file every month. Data is a date-expenditure value pair for each `serviceId`. It is also possible that in a monthly file there are corrections for the data sent in previous months. The value in more recent file is more authentic value. We have to design an ingestion process with detailed data model and data flow diagram as how to store the date and expenditures for each `serviceId` keeping in mind the traceability of records. There are chances that the next file may contain updates.

2) Input: CSV file with the following structure:

```
Sr No.  Header

Column 1    serviceId
Column 2    month
Column 3    d1
Column 4    d2
Column 5    d3
Column 6    d4
Column 7    d5
Column 8    d6
Column 9    d7
Column 10   d8
Column 11   d9
Column 12   d10
Column 13   d11
Column 14   d12
Column 15   d13
Column 16   d14
Column 17   d15
Column 18   d16
Column 19   d17
Column 20   d18
Column 21   d19
Column 22   d20
Column 23   d21
Column 24   d22
Column 25   d23
Column 26   d24
Column 27   d25
Column 28   d26
Column 29   d27
Column 30   d28
Column 31   d29
Column 32   d30
Column 33   d31
```

Note:

- a.   The date corresponding to first non-null value has to be
  considered as starting date.
- b.   The date corresponding to last
  non-null value has to be considered as closing date.
- c.   NULL in CSV
  between starting and closing date must be considered as 0.00 for
  calculation purpose only.
- Sample Input:

  `serviceId,month,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18,d19,d20,d21,d22,d23,d24,d25,d26,d27,d28,d29,d30,d31
  FEUSA0002V,200107,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,26.2866666667,,,,,,,25.5166666667,25.3333333333,25.7,25.8333333333,,,25.8333333333,26.1666666667`

  The month column represents the month eg 201707 represents 2017-07. Each day value is represented by the column number (d1 of 201707 is 2017-07-01, d2 of 201707 is 2017-07-02 and so on).

4) Problem Statement:

- a. For each serviceId, find out the dates for which the value data is missing and prepare a ‘|’ separated list of the dates so that we can revert to fetch data from TestCompany Corporation.
- b. Store the transformed data as given in 5.b. Total is sum of all the available values.

5) Desired Output CSV:

- a.

  `serviceId,missing_dates
  FEUSA0002V, 2001-07-18|2001-07-19|2001-07-20|2001-07-21|2001-07-22|2001-07-23`
- b.

  `serviceId,StartDate,EndDate,Total
  FEUSA0002V, 2017-07-01,2017-10-31,369.1458`

Sample of INPUT FEED  (Multiple rows with same serviceid)

```
ServiceId,month,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8,d9,d10,d11,d12,d13,d14,d15,d16,d17,d18,d19,d20,d21,d22,d23,d24,d25,d26,d27,d28,d29,d30,d31
F0CAN062AH,201706,,31.55,,,31.48,31.39,31.42,31.42,31.46,,,31.29,,31.12,31.13,,,,31.33,,31.31,,31.6,,,31.65,31.46,31.64,31.34,,
F0CAN062AH,201707,,,,31.31,,,,,,31.09,,,31.43,,,,31.23,,,31.39,,,,,31.29,31.1,31.0,30.88,,,30.87
FEUSA04ABQ,200304,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,26.98,
F0CAN05N3F,201612,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,24.78,24.77,24.8,24.82,,,,,,,,
F0CAN05N3F,201701,,,24.75,,24.96,24.93,,,,24.9,24.96,,24.91,,,24.94,,,24.93,25.12,,,25.0,25.1,,,,,,,25.23
F0CAN05N3F,201702,25.29,25.22,25.27,,,25.29,25.35,,,25.8,,,25.87,,26.02,,,,,,,26.3,,25.93,,,25.77,,,,
```

Comment: For question a: I suppose you want the dates sorted ?

Answer (score 0):

For question a:

[image]

1. One way of doing it is to `normalize` the csv file, so that the resulting flow is 4 columns: ServiceId, month, day and value. The parameters as in the image below would be pretty annoying to write if you weren't helped by the "`Get fields` button.
2. You then have to compute the date from the month and d# field. I would do it in a `Javascript` step, which allows at the same time to put the date in ISO format. The Javascript is

   var date = new Date(month.substr(0,4), month.substr(5,2)-1, substr(day,1));
3. Then `filter` the ServiceId and Dates with a non null value.
4. If you need the date sorted: `Sort` them by ServiceId, date
5. `Group`the flow by ServiceId, and `Concatenate strings separated by` "|", with `subject` = date, and `name` the result "missing_dates".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For question b.

[image]

Do exactly the same, except the last step is a `Group by` ServiceId, where

- StartDate is the `first-non null value` of date
- EndDate is the last non null value`of date
- Total is the sum of value.

Not that, in this case, the `Filter` non null values is optional.